# Cordova inAppBrowser in Capacitor not rotating on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser, capacitor

I am transferring a web application from Cordova to Capacitor and everything is working perfectly except for the inAppBrowser plugin. Since the Capacitor browser plugin is very limited, we need to use the old Cordova plugin still. Currently, we are using a few other Cordova plugins in Capacitor that all work as intended.

The problem I'm having is when a browser is opened inside the app, it won't rotate when the device is turned. This only occurs on iPhones though. On Android devices and iPads, the browser rotates with the device as it should. The iOS version doesn't seem to matter as well since I've tried it on multiple versions on both iPhones and iPads. The app itself is designed to rotate with the device and you can see the layout and status bar rotate behind the browser while the browser window doesn't change. The browser opens in a portrait orientation no matter how the device and app are oriented before opening it. I have also tried changing the orientation in the code with cordova-plugin-screen-orientation but the same thing happens where the app rotates behind the browser. Below are some pictures of an iPhone and an iPad rotated with a browser open in the app. The only real code used for this is to open the browser and an example of how that is done is `cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://google.com', '_blank', 'location=no,enableViewportScale=yes,zoom=yes')`

To me, it seems like there is something different with how iPhones and iPads rotate or how the plugin interacts differently with these devices. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

[iPhone Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3f8j7.png) [iPad Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQOgN.png)

Comment: Some code may help others to understand you?

Comment: @Wsculver, I have the exact same problem. Did you manage to find a solution for this issue?